# Adding an Ienumerable list in ViewModel which will be Enumerated In View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, join, ienumerable

I have a list of services in a Database table which i can easily display in the View by using

```
@Modeltype IEnumerable(Of ServicesTestViewModel)

@For Each item In Model

    @item.ServiceName 
    @<br/>
    @item.ServiceDescription 
    @<br/>
    @<br />

Next
```

My ViewModel is as follows

```
Public Class ServicesTestViewModel

    Public Property ServiceName As String
    Public Property ServiceDescription As String
    Public Property AdditionalQuestions As IEnumerable(Of ServiceAdditionalQuestions)

End Class
```

The Services Table has a relationship with another table called AdditionalQuestions which is a list of questions that relate to the service by id. so for each row in a service has a list of additional questions and i want to display it all as a list. Here is my Linq with the join casting toList()

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
        Using db As New EzipizyMarch2014Entities
            Dim query = (From service In db.BusinessServices
                         Join additional In db.ServiceAdditionalQuestions On service.ID Equals additional.ServiceID
                             Select New ServicesTestViewModel With { _
                             .ServiceName = service.ServiceName, _
                             .ServiceDescription = service.ServiceDescription, _
                             .AdditionalQuestions = additional}).ToList
            Return View(query)
        End Using
    End Function
```

Im trying to generate a list and populate the AdditionalQuestions for each Service

Thanks

**Fixed View**

```
@Modeltype IEnumerable(Of ServicesTestViewModel)




<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

        @For Each item In Model

        @item.ServiceName 
        @<br/>
        @item.ServiceDescription 
        @<br/>
        @<br />

@<br />
@<br />


        For Each question In item.MyQuestion
         @question
                @<br/>
            Next


        Next

</body>
</html>
```

**Fixed ViewModel, I used a list(of string) instead of ienumerable**

```
  Public Class ServicesTestViewModel
    Public Property ServiceName As String
    Public Property ServiceDescription As String
    Public Property MyQuestion As List(Of String)
End Class
```

**Fixed Linq Query**

```
 Function Index() As ActionResult
        Using db As New EzipizyMarch2014Entities

            Dim query = (From service In db.BusinessServices
                         Select New ServicesTestViewModel With { _
                             .ServiceName = service.ServiceName, _
                             .ServiceDescription = service.ServiceDescription, _
                             .MyQuestion = service.ServiceAdditionalQuestions.Select(Function(x) x.Question).ToList}).ToList

            Return View(Query)
        End Using
    End Function
```

Comment: @Costas...question is not clear.... What issue are you facing here?

Comment: how do i populate the additionalquestions as a list also and display it on the view within the for each loop for the list of services.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525421/using-list-in-a-model-value-in-linq-query. This answered my question and is exactly what i need to fix my solution i will update my code above

Comment: Then please vote to close your question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, finally I have decided to create a list and pass List to my view instead of IEnumerable.

this is the code example that worked for me.

```
 [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult List()
                {         

 IOrderedEnumerable<MyDomainClass> MyDomainClassCol = MyServiceObject.GetList();        

 List<myViewModelClass> viewModelList = new List<myViewModelClass>();

                foreach (var entity in MyDomainClassCol )
                    {
                    var myViewModelObject= new ViewModelClass();    
                    entity.Map(myViewModelObject);  

                    viewModelList.Add(myViewModelObject);
                    }

                return View("List", myViewModelObject);
                }
```

also in my view I get List, like below:

```
 @model List<YourProjectName.YourViewModelClassName>
```

...
and in order to have access to list data add below loop between `<tbody> /tbody>`

```
  @foreach (var item in @Model)  {
                           <tr>
                               <td>@item.YourViewModelMember1 </td>
                               <td>@item.YourViewModelMember2  </td>
                               <td>@item.YourViewModelMember3 </td>
                           </tr>
                           }
```